# Modify output of Power Automate "Get file content" and insert the result into a new file

Tags: power-automate

Using Power Automate I'd love to achieve the following:

- Extract content of a Word template file
- Replace placeholders in the body text with dynamic outputs of previous actions
- Create new file with the result

(In short is like to use *Populate Microsoft Word template* action without paying Power Automate premium)

The only near-solution I have come across is of decoding base64 output of *Get file content* to string, using replace on that and re-encoding back to base64 before resuming the flow (I.e. create file etc..)

```
base64(Replace(base64ToString(outputs('Get_file_content')),'<Placeholder>', 'Text to insert'))
```

This obviously doesn't work. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: The approach above would need the file to be "unzipped", then you can do the string replacement, and then re-zip. Not a simple task in Power Automate. Alternatively, see if this approach works for you via SharePoint document library columns, and Quick Parts: https://wonderlaura.com/2019/01/09/microsoft-flow-quick-parts/

Comment: Thanks Sam, I have tried it and it works to an extent. But is a bit of a ghetto solution. I'm looking for something more stable. Now looking into your advise on unzipping the file. Any tips you can offer on that would be most welcome.

Comment: Hopefully this article will get you going: [Extract text from Word docx files with Power Automate](https://www.tachytelic.net/2021/05/power-automate-extract-text-from-word-docx-file/)